# Is there an R function for checking membership in a vector?

Tags: r

I often run into a situation where I have two vectors and I want to check if each element of vector 1 is in vector 2. I typically do it with an `sapply()` but wanted to know of there is a more concise way to do it or a single built in function for this. For example:

```
v1 = c(1,1,3,4,5,7)
v2 = c(1,5)
# desired output: [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# my solution
sapply(v1, function(x) x %in% v2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can just use `%in%` as it is vectorized

```
v1 %in% v2
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```